# what is the easiest way to make a copy of document object with javascript only

Tags: javascript, object, clone, document

The copy of the document object should act just like ... document object after its copied, but totally detached from the actual dom reference. What I mean by that is -- if we save this copy of document as `var documentCopy` documentCopy should be able to run `.getElementsByClass('xx')` on itself just as `document` would able to, but the modification of it will not affect the original `document` object.

Is that possible?

I am open to all libraries except jQuery.

Comment: The real question is why on earth you would need something like that ?

Comment: @adeneo generate pdf doc

Comment: save it in a function, referencing with this in the outerscope. but not working that way, the actual dom still gets referenced

Comment: If you give some details about what your intended purpose is there might be better ways to go about it than trying to copy the document object in javascript.

Comment: @Ezeewei and how cloning `document` will help you generating pdf doc?

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee sry that's the company secret lol not my work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`.cloneNode(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) to get a full copy of the DOM. Some things like custom properties won't get copied though. Probably not much of an issue, since you should use `data-` attributes and the `dataset` property anyway, which will get copied with the clone.

```js
var pre = document.querySelector("pre");

// custom properties will not get cloned
pre.customProp = "foobar";

// data- attributes/properties will get cloned
pre.dataset.foo = "bar";

// clone the document
var documentCopy = document.cloneNode(true);

// show that DOM selection works on the copy
console.log("clone found ", documentCopy.getElementsByClassName("foo").length, "'foo' nodes");

// the custom property did not get cloned
console.log("custom prop:", documentCopy.querySelector("pre").customProp);

// but the dataset property did
console.log("dataset prop:", documentCopy.querySelector("pre").dataset.foo);
```

```css
pre {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>

<pre></pre>
```

The `true` argument makes it a deep copy instead of just cloning the outer element.

Answer (score 1):

The `document` keyword is going to give you [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)) to the document -- not a copy. So in your example, changes to `documentCopy` **would** affect the original document.

Under the hood, browsers maintain the document hierarchy as linked "node" objects, so there isn't a great way to just "copy" all the objects and their current state.

In order to get new "copies" of node objects, you need to get their HTML contents as a string, and then insert new nodes into the DOM using that HTML markup:

```js
// get the original body HTML
var bodyHTML = document.body.innerHTML;

// create a new div and set its contents
var copiedNode = document.createElement("div");
copiedNode.innerHTML = bodyHTML;

// inser the new nodes
document.body.appendChild(copiedNode);

// modify the copied nodes
copiedNode.firstElementChild.setAttribute("style", "color: blue");
```

```html
<p style="color: red;">paragraph one</p>
```